# Inkscape - how to change double lines font inside the rectangle box?

Tags: inkscape, fonts, text, workflow

I am new to inkscape. I'm primarily using it for make flow diagrams. I've put landscape orientation of the page.
When I add text inside rectangles created they come to be of double lines. I've font times new roman and font size as 36. Please see attached screenshot.

I'm on OSX Mac Inkscape 1.3 (0e150ed, 2023-07-21).

How do I change the double lines?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given to your text a stroke, but no fill. Select the text object. Do NOT select anything else. Remove the stroke and define a fill color in the Fill&Stroke panel. If you select also the rectangle at the same time it gets the same fill color.